# http basic authorization with Flask REST

Tags: javascript, flask, authorization

I am developing a simple REST service in flask.
I have been trying to implement basic authorization.
Whilst, I can pass the username and password from the webpage using manual entry, I can't seem to read them from the header.

Here is my code:

On the server

```
def test():
    if request.authorization and request.authorization.username == '***' and request.authorization.password == '***':
        return "Authorized"
    else:
        return make_response('Authorization failed', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm ="Login Required"'})
```

On the client - using JavaScript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#authButton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa("***:***")
            },            
            url: "********:5001/",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(){
                console.log("success");
        },
            error: function (){
                console.log("error");
        },


        });
    });
});

</script
```

>

I have also tried the Javascript code without the xhr fields section, but for neither do I get anything returned at all.
If I don't send the headers from the client it works and simply asks for manual input of the username and password.
All I'm trying to do is authenticate from the header.
Any pointers would be very gratefully received.

Comment: you should make use of JWT tokens, and you should not send usernames and passwords as plain text in the headers whether as dicts or directly inscribed into the headers.

Comment: Thanks Maestro.inc. I do have a version that uses jwt and it works, in that it returns a token, but I still can't read the username and password from the header. I still have to enter the username and password manually upon connection

Comment: Since you are using Flask, I would recommend a Flask_JWT-Extended. I have tried it and it works and I could paste a sample code to assist with retrieving the user details

Comment: Yes, maestro.inc I would be happy to try this out. I would like to understand how to read from the header though, just to know what is going on and why my code, just doesn't seem to work. I feel as if I am just doing something stupid or missing something obvious, because I've seen other posts which seem to say this should work.

Comment: Okay for your code you, first the origin of whatever is in the header should originate from the backend(Your flask code) and get sent to the frontend. You can use personal `algorithms` and `hashing` methods to encode the header object such that it contains the `password` and `user identity` of whoever sent the request. Whenever the header gets sent to the backend with a request, it is decoded and the information of whoever sent the requests get read. Also while using Flask prefer `request['Authorization]` and request.get('Authorization)' to request.Authorization

Comment: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ (flask jwt extended)

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this. Maybe to rephrase. Why doesn't this code<br/>    * if request.authorization and request.authorization.username == 'test' and request.authorization.password == 'test': * <br/> not read the header?